# What is the proper way to change Macintosh HD icon used on Mac Startup Manager with FileVault2 enabled?

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, catalina, startup, icon

I have macOS Catalina 10.15.3 (FileVault2 is enabled) installed with Windows 10 in dual-boot and I was able to sucessfully change the Windows icon, but I can't figure out how to modify the icon for my Macintosh HD drive.

I tried with SIP disabled :

```
- to replace ".VolumeIcon.icns" inside /System/Volume/Data/ by a custom one
- To use the Get-Info box from the Finder and changing the icon from here
```

The changes are working inside the Finder but not when holding "Alt" and using the Mac Startup Manager..

Is there a proper way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you try updating the preboot volume? That's what the firmware looks at before it can unlock the rest.

Comment: I just gave it a try and used this command : sudo cp /Users/admin/Desktop/icon.icns /Volume/Preboot/*****/System/Library/CoreService/.VolumeIcon.icns but sadly it didn't worked.

Comment: Does the Mac ask for the password to unlock the before or after displaying the icons in the Startup Manager?

Comment: The only password asked before i can get into the Startup Manager is the Firmware password so not related i think. I can make a video of the boot process it that could help.

Comment: Here is a video of the mac booting : https://youtu.be/y3dNZ_jmWm8

Comment: I can post a answer to this question where you can change both the icon and text on the startup manager display for macOS. However, this answer would require using rEFInd to silently instruct the firmware to boot macOS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! But sadly in this current setup i'm not allowed to use any 3rd party boot manager, but if it comes to that i will post a new question asking how to do it using rEFInd so you can help me.

Answer (score 3):

> Note: Not all `icns` files are compatible with the firmware installed in your Mac. You may need to convert an `icns` file to a different format before the file will be recognized by the firmware.

You first need to determined the identifier for the APFS `Preboot` volume from the output of the command `diskutil list`. Below is an example.

```
/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +898.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Muskie                  32.2 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 120.5 MB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.0 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      8.6 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume Snapper - Data          741.9 GB   disk1s5
   6:                APFS Volume Snapper                 11.2 GB    disk1s6
```

From the above output, the identifier for the APFS `Preboot` volume is `disk1s2`. If you have a different identifier, then make the appropriate substitutions. Enter the following commands to copy the `icns` file to the `Preboot` volume.

```
diskutil mount disk1s2
sudo cp /Users/admin/Desktop/icon.icns /Volumes/Preboot/.VolumeIcon.icns
diskutil unmount disk1s2
```

In the above example, there are two versions of macOS installed in the container. The `Muskie` volume has High Sierra installed. The `Snapper` and `Snapper - Data` volumes have Catalina installed.  When booted to the Mac Startup Manager, the `.VolumeIcon.icns` file, stored in the root of the `Preboot` volume, is used to display the same image for both operating systems.

If you wanted different images in the Mac Startup Manager for each version of macOS, then you could install both versions of MacOS in different containers. Or, the same container could be used, but I am not sure if this would work when encryption is employed. An example is given below.

The previous example used the `/Users/admin/Desktop/icon.icns` file. In this example, this file is replaced by the two files `High Sierra.icns` and `Catalina.icns` stored in the `Desktop` folder of your Catalina account. Images of both files are shown below.

[image: High Sierra] [image: Catalina]

The following steps could be used to install the `icns` files.

> Note: You do **not** have to disable SIP.

1. Boot to Catalina and enter the commands given below to remove any existing `.VolumeIcon.icns` file from the root of the `Preboot` volume.

   ```
   diskutil mount disk1s2
   sudo rm /Volumes/Preboot/.VolumeIcon.icns
   diskutil unmount disk1s2
   ```
2. Enter the following command to install the image for High Sierra.

   ```
   sudo cp "$HOME/Desktop/HighSierra.icns /Volumes/Muskie/.VolumeIcon.icns
   ```
3. Boot to High Sierra and enter the command given below to install the image of Catalina.

   ```
   sudo cp "/Volumes/Snapper - Data/Users/$USER/Desktop/Catalina.icns" /Volumes/Snapper/.VolumeIcon.icns
   ```

### Update for Big Sur

The `Preboot` volume is already mounted at `/System/Volumes/Preboot`. To change this volume while using macOS Big Sur, first you will have to disable SIP.

Comment: I can confirm this worked perfectly on Catalina, unfortunately I don't seem to be able to mount Preboot on Big Sur. It says "Mounted", but it's not available. And if I try to unmount I'm presented with: Volume Preboot on disk1s2 failed to unmount: dissented by PID 0 (kernel_task)

Comment: @DIYglenn: I updated my answer. Does this update satisfy your comment?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it in Big Sur by booting to Recovery Mode, mounting the (encrypted) macOS - Data partition in Terminal, and then running the above commands (Copying from my mounted main partition). This does not require deactivating SIP.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for posting an answer.. Could you specify what the "above commands" are? In David Anderson's question there are several sets of commands.